# Python Web-Scraper using BeautifulSoup - Find the right html line for the information im looking for

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I just switched from C to Python and to get some practice I want to code a simple web-scraper for price comparison.
It works so far that the program goes to every website I tell it to, and it gives me the information of the website back as html.
But when I try to tell BeautifulSoup to just find the prices, the output is 'None'.
So I think that the html address, I am passing to BeautifulSoup as the price information is wrong.

I would be really grateful if anyone could help me with that problem or just has some tips and tricks for a beginner!
I will add my python code and the link to the website since it looks kinda messy if I put the html code here, just tell me if you need anything more.
Thank you!

https://www.momox.de/offer/9783833879500

I would just need the part where it says 8,87€ (or whatever €, price is changing constantly), but looks like i got the wrong part of the html code..

```
 import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def GetISBN():
    Lagerbestand = open("ISBN.txt", "r")
    for ISBN in Lagerbestand.readlines():
        url = f'https://www.momox.de/offer/{ISBN}'
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        price= soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'text-center text-xxl font-medium searchresult-price'})
        print(price)
    Lagerbestand.close()

GetISBN()
```

The ISBN.txt is a file with 1 article number per line (This part works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The price is loaded with Ajax request from external URL. You can use this example how to load it using `requests` module:

```py
import json
import requests

api_url = "https://api.momox.de/api/v4/offer/"
params = {"ean": "9783833879500"}  # <--- change this to your EAN
headers = {
    "X-API-TOKEN": "2231443b8fb511c7b6a0eb25a62577320bac69b6",
    "X-CLIENT-VERSION": "r5299-76accf6",
    "X-MARKETPLACE-ID": "momox_de",
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params, headers=headers).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data["price"])
```

Prints:

```
11.44
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! How can I get the api_url and the headers data in general for example from different websites? And is it okay to use this data or is it actually somehow restricted to use? thank you very much!

Comment: @lasse3434 Different websites behave differently, but generally - open Network Tab in Developer Tools and observe where the page is making requests. Oftern you will find some api URL and what parameters, headers to use.